# How to write a Scheme procedure which takes an ill formed list and returns a well formed one with the same structure?

Tags: recursion, scheme, nested-lists

I am trying to implement a Scheme procedure which takes a nested list of numbers that may not be well-formed and returns a nested list with the same content and structure, but which does not have any dots when displayed.

Examples:

```
scm> (reform '((1 . 2) 3))
((1 2) 3)
scm> (reform '(1 (2 3 . 4) . 3))
(1 (2 3 4) 3)
scm> (reform '(1 . ((2 3 . 4) . 3)))
(1 (2 3 4) 3)
```

My current solution:

```
(define (reform s)
  (cond
   ((null? s) nil)
   ((number? s) s)
   ((null? (cdr s)) (car s))
   (else (list (reform (car s)) (reform (cdr s))))
  )
)
```

This solution does remove all the dots, but it doesn't maintain the form of the input. How can I rewrite my implementation so that it doesn't create extra lists which don't exist in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This passes the tests.

```
(define (reform xs)
  (cond
    [(null? xs) xs]
    [(and (pair? xs) (pair? (cdr xs)))
     (cons (reform (car xs)) (reform (cdr xs)))]
    [(and (pair? xs) (null? (cdr xs)))
     (list (reform (car xs)))]
    [(pair? xs)
     (cons (reform (car xs)) (list (reform (cdr xs))))]
    [else xs]))

(reform '((1 . 2) 3))
(reform '(1 (2 3 . 4) . 3))
(reform '(1 . ((2 3 . 4) . 3)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why @soegaard has so many tests wether the list is a pair when the obvious would be to do the exception first:

```scm
(define (dot->proper xs)
  (cond ((null? xs) '())
        ((not (pair? xs)) (list xs))
        ((pair? (car xs)) (cons (dot->proper (car xs)) (dot->proper (cdr xs))))
        (else  (cons (car xs) (dot->proper (cdr xs))))))

(dot->proper '((1 . 2) 3))           ; ==> ((1 2) 3)
(dot->proper '(1 (2 3 . 4) . 3))     ; ==> (1 (2 3 4) 3)
(dot->proper '(1 . ((2 3 . 4) . 3))) ; ==> (1 (2 3 4) 3)
```